# How can i add namespaces in XDocument with out knowing the attributes and values?

Tags: linq-to-xml

for example

```
           XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(myxmldocument.NameTable);
           nsmgr.AddNamespace("xdp", "http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/");
           nsmgr.AddNamespace("config", "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/");
```

similarly how can we add in XDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = myXDocument.ToString();//my XDocument  corresponds to our existing XDocument
XPathDocument xpath = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(s));
        XPathNavigator pathnavigator= xpath .CreateNavigator();
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(pathnavigator.NameTable);
```